# c++ usual arithmetic conversions: cpp.sh vs godbolt different results - who is wrong?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, expression, implicit-conversion

Here is a simple showcase of standard arithmetic conversion:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    unsigned long a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    long long c = -1;
    
    cout << (c < a*b) << endl;
}
```

godbolt returns 0, cpp.sh returns 1.

Standard (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/usual_arithmetic_conversions) says:

> Stage 4 ...
>
> - If the integer conversion rank of U is greater than or equal to the    integer conversion rank of S, C is U.
> - Otherwise, if S can represent all of the values of U, C is S.
> - Otherwise, C is the unsigned integer type corresponding to S.

Which compiler is **wrong** and **why**?

Comment: You can simplify the example by completely removing `b`, it isn’t needed to show the different unsigned comparison behaviour.

Comment: Nice, thank you, but still, can you please clarify and explain why 2 compilers yield different results, but standard obviously specified what needs to happen.

Comment: cpp.sh is a 32 bit compiler. That possibly explains the difference.

Comment: But standard is standard. It covers both 32bit and 64bit architectures. Conforming to standard should give the same functionality (results) independent of architecture.

Comment: With a 32 bit compiler, the sizes of fundamental types can change (e.g. longs) and so things like this sentence can result in different outputs:
`Otherwise, if S can represent all of the values of U, C is S.`

Comment: @MikeVine Good point, but using the WebAssembly clang compiler on Godbolt (which is also 32 bits) also returns 0, not 1: https://godbolt.org/z/6qfEPhx7b

Comment: @MikeVine the size depends on implementation and not the bitness. A 16-bit compiler can have 128-bit int without problem. Or realistically 64-bit MSVC uses 32-bit long but 64-bit \*nix uses 64-bit long

Answer (score 9):

The result depends on whether `sizeof( unsigned long )` is equal to `sizeof( long long )`. That is whether the type `long long` can represent all positive values of the type `unsigned long` or not.

If it can not represent values of the type `unsigned long` then the common type of the operands of this expression

```
(c < a*b)
```

will be `unsigned long long` due to the usual arithmetic conversions and as a result the expression yields the value `false` because `-1` is converted to a very big positive value of the type `unsigned long long`.

Otherwise if the common type of the operands of the expression is `long long` because as mentioned above `sizeof( unsigned long )` is less than `sizeof( long long )` and the type `long long` can represent all positive values of the type `unsigned long`, the expression yields the value `true`.

Try to output values of the expressions `sizeof( unsigned long )` and `sizeof( long long )` in the used systems.

Also you can run the following test program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    unsigned long x;
    long long y;

    std::cout << "sizeof( unsigned long ) = "
        << sizeof( unsigned long ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof( long long ) = "
        << sizeof( long long ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), long long> is "
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), long long> << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), unsigned long long> is "
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), unsigned long long> << '\n';
}
```

For example using MS VS C++ the obtained result is

```
sizeof( unsigned long ) = 4
sizeof( long long ) = 8
std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), long long> is true
std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), unsigned long long> is false
```

using clang on godbolt the obtained result is

```
sizeof( unsigned long ) = 8
sizeof( long long ) = 8
std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), long long> is false
std::is_same_v<decltype( y + x ), unsigned long long> is true
```

From the C++17 Standard (8 Expressions)

> 11 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
> enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
> way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
> the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*,
> which are defined as follows:
>
> > ...
>
> (11.5.4) — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer
> type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with
> unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
> converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> (11.5.5) — **Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the
> unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with
> signed integer type.**

A similar problem can occur in MS VS C++ with objects of types `long` and `unsigned int` because the types have equal sizes.

Pay attention to that neither in C++ nor in C sizes of standard integer types are fixed except of types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` sizes of which are equal to `1` by definition.

To get the expected result in your program you could write for example

```
std::cout << (c < static_cast<long long>( a*b ) ) << std::endl;
```

Or if your compiler supports C++20 you can use standard function `std::cmp_less` declared in header `<utility>`. Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    long long x = -1;
    unsigned long y = 0;

    std::cout << "sizeof( long long ) = " << sizeof( long long ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof( unsigned long ) = " << sizeof( unsigned long ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "( x < y ) is " << ( x < y ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::cmp_less( x, y ) is " << std::cmp_less( x, y ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output might look like

```
sizeof( long long ) = 8
sizeof( unsigned long ) = 8
( x < y ) is false
std::cmp_less( x, y ) is true
```